# Chromecast DRM License Url - Widevine

Tags: chromecast

I have read that Styled Media Receiver supports DRM if the licence URL is embedded in the media manifest.
The problem is that I want to play mpd pretected content on chromecast. How can I handle the license url and custom data on sender side, without creating a custom media receiver?
Where I should set licenseUrl? Thanks.

Comment: have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a custom receiver to achieve that.

Comment: Yes, I've wrote a simple custom receiver, like the example from google developers .

But when I try to cast, the app is mirroring the website. 
What should I add extra? What am I doing wrong.

I can't acheive this with Media Player Library from sender side?